# Find the sum of an even number from a list of integers

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, digits

```
input-258345
    output-14
    ex-2+8+4=14
```

```
myList = input()
result = 0
for i in myList:
  if not i % 2:
    result += i

print(result)
```

I am getting an error:

```
if not i % 2:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: `input` always returns one string. `i` is its single character

Comment: sidenote: i always feel `i % 2 == 0` is clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mylist = list(input())
result = 0
for i in mylist:
  if int(i) % 2 ==0:
    result += int(i)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

`myList` is a string, and you are iterating over its characters. If you want to treat them as digits, you'll need to explicitly convert them. E.g.:

```py
for i in myList:
  num = int(i)
  if not num % 2:
    result += num
```